# Replace text starting with & symbom Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a string in oracle column example `emp.id=100&empHelper.userTab=2` I want to use REPLACE function to replace `'&empHelper.userTab=2'` with empty string.

`&` symbol is creating problem , I want to use escape char to consider '&empHelper.userTab=2' as text to replace in replace function instead of using set define off .

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Comment: What is the "problem" you have? If you are using `sqlplus` you need to run `set define off` otherwise the `&` is used for parameters.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, you just answered the question.

Comment: I am executing UPDATE  EMPLOYEE SET URL= REPLACE(URL, '&empHelper.userTab=2', '') where application_id = 'manager';  Its taking &empHelper as input parameter.

Comment: Don't post code or additional information in comments. [edit] your question (and read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to understand how you can format your code)

Comment: Just don't use the ampersand, use CHR function instead. This will avoid needing to set define off. REPLACE(myvar,CHR(38),'_')